# Changing default showed price

Tags: squarespace

I need help with changing the display price on my website. I use a site called GloriaFood to receive orders, but it automatically shows the lowest price. Is there any code I can use to make each item show what I want myself? Im using Squarespace to make my website, and I really need this to change before I can finalize it.

The link to the site is namnam.squarespace.com and password is namnam2021. Just press on the button that says "Bestill nå!" to see the menu. You will see that the price of the first item is display as 139,00 but I want it to say 179,00 instead.

I would happily just change the value for each of them, but I need to know what code to use. Maybe someone could make a template for the code so I can just change the div-variable and change the corresponding number. Btw I see that you can add code to the header or footer on the site, if that helps.